# Showing that the infinite series $\sum_1^\infty \left(\frac {1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, telescopic-series

If we consider an infinite series witht the $n^{th}$ term $$a_n= \frac {1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}$$
for $n\ge1$

I am used to calculate the value to which a geometric series converges by looking at the coefficient. However, here I do not have the coefficient but the series itself. How could I show that this infinite series converges and calculate its sum?

Comment: I would recommend finding a common denominator, and using comparison test with $1/n^2$.

Comment: You can compute the sum, yes. Compute the sum of the first $n$ terms. Note that many of the terms cancel. The $\frac{1}{1}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ from the first two terms and the $-\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $-\frac{1}{n+2}$ from the last two terms don't cancel, but the other fractions appear in positive and negative pairs.

Comment: $\sum_1^N a_n = \sum_1^N \left(\frac {1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right) =1 +\frac12-\frac1{N+1}-\frac1{N+2}$

Comment: @user; From your expression, I can see that when $n$ approaches infinity, the sum evaluates to $\frac {3}{2}$. But how did you obtain that formula for the sum?

Comment: @Aristarchus_  $\sum_1^N a_n = \sum_1^N \left(\frac {1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right) =1 +\frac12+\ldots +\frac1 {N-1}+\frac1 N-\frac13-\frac14-\ldots-\frac1{N}-\frac1{N+1}-\frac1{N+2}$

Comment: Could you please write down $a_1=\frac 11-\frac13$, $a_2=\frac 12-\frac14$, $a_3=\frac 13-\frac15$, $a_4=\frac 14-\frac16$, $a_5=\frac 15-\frac17$ on a sheet of paper, and compute for us (without computing, just cancel terms...) $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5\ ?$$

Comment: I would try noting that: $$a_n = b_n + c_n$$ where $$b_n = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} $$ $$c_n = \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} $$ Hence $b_n$ and $c_n$ are both telescopic and their sum can be computed easily…

Comment: @dan_fulea; $a_1 =\frac{2}{3}  a_2 = 2/8  a_3 = 2/15  a_4 = 2/24$

Comment: Just let $b_n=\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ and observe that $a_n=b_n-b_{n+1}$. You get a telescopic series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a geometric series, but it converges. Evaluate the partial sum:

$$\require{cancel}\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\left(1-\cancel{\frac13}\right)+\left(\frac12-\cancel{\frac14}\right)+\left(\cancel{\frac13}-\cancel{\frac15}\right)+\ldots+\left(\cancel{\frac1n}-\frac1{n+2}\right)=$$

$$=\frac32+\frac1{n+2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac32$$

Comment: Hi, my friend ! Long time no see you here. Are you OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Salut, mon ami ! I am, and I have been, very well, thanks. It is just that in the way this site is managed I don't find it so appealing to enter often... What about you? I hope you're fine.

Comment: @user 58 Indeed so, thanks. Yet I can't see where the term $\;\frac1{M+1}\;$ comes from

Comment: Look at the second partial sum. You will be able to  see.

Comment: Although the result is correct, the identity is wrong. The partial sum should be equal to $\frac 3 2 - \frac 1{n + 1} - \frac 1{n + 2}$ - which was correctly posted in a comment above.